# How to check if the variable contains the same string as a file?

Tags: bash

My variables name is `A` and my files name is `dogs.txt`. I need to check if the variables text is the same as `dogs.txt` (contains the same string). 
What is the best way to do it?

I tried this

```
if [ cat dogs.txt == "$A" ] ; then  echo "equal" ; fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ A=foo
$ echo foo > foo.txt
$ B=$(<foo.txt)
$ [[ $A == $B ]] && echo yes
yes
```